# Protecting/Un-protecting worksheet in shared workbook with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am wanting to put a notes section into a workbook, where notes can be added about a particular row in a worksheet. There will be lots of rows.

I want these notes to be uneditable once they have been written, so they can't be tampered with.

Previously I have done this by unprotecting, then protecting the worksheet to enter the note which is captured in VBA. However this workbook needs to be shared, which means  you can't unprotect or protect a workbook either in VBA or manually.

Excel really isn't the right platform for this, as it's basically a small CRM, but unfortunately for the moment it's the only thing available and that can't change for now, so need to try and find a way to make it work, any idea's?

I have tried protecting the workbook with UserInterfaceOnly:= True, and that works great until the workbook is closed and re-opened then it fails and then can't unprotect or protect the workbook.

Comment: Use a Worksheet_Change to reverse any change(s) made to the notes section.

Comment: Can't get the notes to go into the notes section is the problem as the worksheet will be protected, need to find a way to unprotect to enter the note in the first place.

Comment: What event or user action determines that the note "is now written" so that it needs to be protected from that point on? What happens when the note is poorly/erroneously formulated/phrased (to say nothing of spelling...) and needs a correction or a rewrite?

Comment: I will be putting a hyperlink in a column on each row entitled "Notes/Actions", the clicking of the hyperlink will trigger the VBA to run and open a Userform, where the user can then decide if they want actions to notes, and to view or add to each of those (they will basically both work the same).
 If they select add, it will capture the note and add it to the notes (all notes for all rows will be stored in a single place), if they select view, the VBA will filter the notes section only to those which relate to the appropriate row (each row will have a hidden ID field and put with the note)